# Sql result duplicated: wrong query spelling or inappropriate database structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have, as part of an ERP system for schools, a table with all the classes given on the centre, relating each class (`cl_id`) with an specific course (`cl_fk_co_id`) and a teacher (`cl_fk_te_id`). As you see, a teacher can be related to several classes with the same course (eg: teacher ID 3 is related to course ID 302 in two classes (ID 39 & ID 42):

[image: table example]

Now I need to SELECT all courses given by this teacher, and list them with a WHILE. Here you have the query:

```
$selectCoursesFilter = select("SELECT * FROM class_conf JOIN course_conf ON co_id=cl_fk_co_id WHERE cl_fk_te_id='3'");

while($registroCourses = consultaRegistro($selectCoursesFilter)){                       
    $course_conf_filter_list_prev.='<option value="'.$registroCourses['co_id'].'">'.$registroCourses['co_name'].'</option>';}
```

This WHILE gives as result 3 `co_id` records instead of two: 306, 302 and 302. In this case, even when 302 is listed twice on the table, and given by the same teacher (classes ID 39 & ID 42), should only be listed once as it is the same course.

I understand it finds 3 records as result of this query, but I do not know the proper way to avoid duplicities between each course. IS DDBB worng structured or is the query wrong spelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM class_conf JOIN
     course_conf
     ON co_id=cl_fk_co_id
WHERE cl_fk_te_id = '3';
```

The data has three dimensions -- courses, classes, and teachers.  You are only looking at two of these.  So, when a course has a teacher but multiple classes, then you get duplicates.

How you solve this depends on what you want to do.  Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT co_id, co_name
FROM class_conf JOIN
     course_conf
     ON co_id = cl_fk_co_id
WHERE cl_fk_te_id = '3';
```

Comment: I am about to try this. Thank u 4 your attention, i'll keep informed

Comment: Yes, this works. It takes only once each co_id matched, right what I needed. I'll take a look at "SELECT DISTINCT" as this is the first time I see it. Very grateful, I'll tick in 9 minutes.